# Firebase real time database type

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, types, geolocation

I recently updated my database and the geolocation function I was using to check and see how far a user was from a location stopped working.  Couldn't figure what was going on until I thought maybe the snapshot was being read as a string instead of a double or long.  This happened when I pushed up some new mountains.  The format I am using is this:

```
"ABasin": {
    "latitude": 39.6425,
    "longitude": -105.8719,
    "name": "Arapahoe Basin"
  }
```

The way to get around the issue is to use parseInt, however this would require a new release (something which takes more time than say fixing the backend right away).

```
let isInsideRadius = isPointWithinRadius(
        {latitude: parseInt(userLatitude), longitude: parseInt(userLongitude)},
        {latitude: parseInt(mountainLatitude), longitude: parseInt(mountainLongitude)},
    // 100 miles is 170 km
    170000
  );
```

How do I go about making sure the type is correct for the real time database to fix this issue without having to deploy to IOS and Android right now.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make sure the type is correct"?  Whose responsibility are you saying that should be?

Comment: @DougStevenson basically my app was always reading those at numbers before and when I reseeded the database the last time they are coming back as strings.  I just don't see what would have changed since I am uploading them the same way.  Not sure if there was an update to firebase real time database recently or what would be making them characterized at strings now

Comment: Nothing has changed in the database.  It will store exactly what you put into it. I suggesting reviewing your code that populates the database and figuring out where the problem issue.  Also, parseInt isn't the right thing for converting things that should be floating point types.  Use parseFloat instead.

Comment: Agreed with Doug here, it's very unlikely (though not impossible) that the wire protocol type has changed between Realtime Database releases. But if you can reproduce it with a specific piece of code on a specific location in your database, I'll take a look to see if I can reproduce it too.

Comment: Ok so I was able to figure out how to reproduce issue by going back and trying to use my old seed and see that it was reading as a number at not a string, but I basically just went old guess and check and kept reseeding, weirdest thing- it's from this mountain:  https://github.com/Sbphillips19/MountainsIssue/blob/master/mountains.js#L182 . Somehow a capital L for Longitude affected all the other values